# how to force serialization in json format for simple String classes?

Tags: json, spring, serialization

i have a code like this :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/student")
public class StudentController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> serviceOk() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("service OK", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and it returns to me

```
service OK
```

and not

```
"service OK"
```

Indeed, "service OK" is a valid JSON format, but service OK is not.
so how can i transform my webservice so that i force serialization in json, even for simple String format ?

Comment: Try the @JsonValue from fasterxml.jackson

Answer (score 0):

You may use gson. The following code should work:

```
// import com.google.gson.Gson; Importing gson library!

private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> serviceOk() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(gson.toJson("service OK"), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Comment: ok i know that but i meaned i wanted to use properties or annotations on the class or method level..